# Dynamic string splitting to get the last word

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a challenge question like "What is your favorite movie?". There could be any question like this. I need last word of the question i.e. movie. without question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

String question =  "What is your favorite movie";

String lastWord = question .substring(question .lastIndexOf(" ")+1);

Answer (score 0):

When you select the element containing your challenge question, you can call `.getText()` (in Java; similar in other languages) to get the text inside. Then, you can use regular expressions or substring utilities in your language to strip out the last word.